# Aws s3 read only bucket policy not working with cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have made a `S3` bucket policy for readonly access to `cloudfront`, i want to restrict `s3` bucket for public and just allow it from referrer urls via `cloudfront` how ever it is not applying my `s3` bucket policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "http referer",
  "Statement": [
 {
   "Sid": "Allow get requests referred by www.def.com and dev.def.com.",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access   Identity XXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
   "Action": "s3:GetObject",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::devmb/*",
   "Condition": {
     "StringLike": {
     "aws:Referer": [
     "http://www.def.com/*",
     "http://dev.def.com/*"
       ]
     }
  }
},
    {
      "Sid": "Explicit deny to ensure requests are allowed only from specific referer.",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::devmb/*",
    "Condition": {
      "StringLike": {
      "aws:Referer": [
      "http://dev.xyx.com/*",
      "http://blog.xyz.com/*"
      ]
     }
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

My content is public right now.

Comment: Please elaborate on "it is not working". Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See [this answer here on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34898823/1695906) particularly the second part -- what you are trying to do is best done with AWS Web Application Firewall (WAF) in front of CloudFront -- not with bucket policies, which require you to custom-tweak CloudFront and will not give you as high of a cache hit ratio as WAF will allow you to achieve (although it is *possible* with bucket policies and CF, without the origin access identity).

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot Thanks for your reply. i have tried this but it showing content at client end however content is blocked if i view it on server. I want  use domain based restrictions. For example,
    www.abc.com/*  (Allowed)
    blog.abc.com/* (Deny)

Comment: "If I view it on server" -- what does that mean?  You request it from a browser running on the web server?  Any direct request (URL typed directly into a browser) would be denied since there would be no ``Referer:` header sent.   If that's what you mean, add a rule to WAF to trust certain IP addresses (such as your own).

Answer (score 0):

**Referer** does not work when using CloudFront because the referer does not appear in the HTTP request header itself. You'll have to use S3 without CloudFront if you wish to restrict access using conditional aws:Referer in the bucket policy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Khalid how can i get it worked with `cloudfront` i tried `aws:SourceIp` but same result :(

Comment: You can refer to this document for available options http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Comment: i have tried `origin access identity` method for `cloudfront` but it's not working. I have followed same reference url