# Why is rails app rendering without CSS after creating Cloudfront distribution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku

My rails app isn't loading the css or js files now upon trying to implement page cache via cloudfront.

I'm using heroku and I setup cloudfront based on these instructions:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn

Done: "To create a CloudFront distribution you will need an Amazon AWS account. Once logged in you can go to the CloudFront control panel and select ‘Create distribution’. When prompted for the delivery method, select 'Web’."

I then added to rails **production.rb**: `config.action_controller.asset_host = "d373p52igaakhgm9.cloudfront.net"`

What could have gone wrong with www.anthonygalli.com? I think I followed all the steps.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Curious to know how you solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the network traffic on your site (e.g. using Developer Console in Chrome), you will notice there is a `403 Forbidden` response to your cloudfront assets.  It seems that your Cloudfront configuration is not quite correct.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/34898823/2611078 for some ideas.